# Input 0 of layer "lstm_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 256)

Tags: keras, nlp, lstm, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to build a generative LSTM model using tensorflow2. I am new to using LSTM layer in tensorflow. the code is given below::

```
vec = layers.TextVectorization(output_sequence_length=maxlen,
                               max_tokens=379)
vec.adapt(use_for_vocab(train)) 
# here i just convert the train dataset into a form suitable to use for vectorization 

voc = vec.get_vocabulary()
voc_size = len(voc)

embed = layers.Embedding(input_dim=voc_size,
                         output_dim=256,
                         mask_zero=True)

inp_word = layers.Input(shape=(maxlen+2,), # maxlen is the maximum length of the sentence in the text
                   name="word_input")      # 2 is added to accommodate start_token and end_token
x_word = embed(inp_word)
x_word = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x_word)
x_word = layers.LSTM(256, return_sequences=True)(x_word)
ops_word = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(name="word_gap")(x_word)
```

Here is the model summary:

**Model: "word_model"**

| Layer (type) | Output Shape | Param # |
| --- | --- | --- |
| word_input (InputLayer) | [(None, 35)] | 0 |
| embedding_1 (Embedding) | (None, 35, 128) | 45184 |
| dropout_6 (Dropout) | (None, 35, 128) | 0 |
| lstm_5 (LSTM) | (None, 35, 256) | 394240 |
| word_gap (GlobalAveragePooling1D) | (None, 256) | 0 |

Total params: 439,424
Trainable params: 439,424
Non-trainable params: 0

---

I have created a prefetched dataset for input. This is how I have built it using the function below:

```
from tensorflow.data import Dataset, AUTOTUNE

def format_dataset(x, y):
  y = Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y)
  data = Dataset.zip((x, y))
  return data.batch(32).prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
```

I am able to compile the model without any error. But, while fitting the model, it is giving the following error:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 235, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'caption_model' (type Functional).
    
    Input 0 of layer "lstm_5" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 128)
```

Cannot understand why input sequence still is two-dimensional in spite of making return_sequences true. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you do embedding for nlp you can do this:

Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)

There I dont know what embed you used

So instead of
x_word = embed(inp_word) you can use
x_word = layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)(inp_word)

Edit:
I ran this code in colab and no problem at all:

```
embed = layers.Embedding(input_dim=1000,output_dim=256,mask_zero=True)

inp_word = layers.Input(shape=(50,), 
                   name="word_input")     
x_word = embed(inp_word)
x_word = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x_word)
x_word = layers.LSTM(256, return_sequences=True)(x_word)
print(x_word.shape) #(None, 50, 256)
ops_word = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(name="word_gap")(x_word)
print(ops_word.shape) #(None, 256)
```

I guess you must preprocessed your data wrong. Is your input data shape like (N, sequence_len)?

Comment: I am not 100% sure if you also need to add input_length=maxlen+2 in your embedding, i think as you are using funcional api this is optional.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add... I have used layers.Embedding only.
Also, I added maxlen + 2 to accomodate a start and an end token in each sentence.

Comment: Hey, how is you input data shape?

Comment: I have added the entire model summary in the question for your reference

Comment: but what is the shape of your x_train and y_train? I guess your problem is this.

Comment: I have built a pre-fetched dataset...
I have now added that code in the question too. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: But what is the shape of x and y?!!! Just print(x.shape) and print(y.shape)